# JavaFX detach from webpage

Tags: java, applet, javafx, javafx-2

As a personal project, I'm making a media player to be embedded in a webpage. I've been playing around with JavaFX 2.2, and I like what I see so far (mp3 support!); also, I've made java applets in the past.

I know with applets, there's a neat feature where you can (in Windows) left-alt click and drag, and the applet will be come detached from the page and can float around the screen. You can even leave the page, and the applet will stay open. I really like this feature - it doesn't hurt that it makes it look like I went an extra mile for that functionality. Do JavaFX  applications embedded in webpages have this feature? Searching so far has given me no results, and the key/click combos I've tried don't work.

JavaFX seems to be up-and-coming (maybe) and applets seem out of date for the most part, so I'd like go with JavaFX with this project. That also allows me to play around with making my own preloader.

Is there any way to get my media player to have the detach functionality? I know I can embed JavaFX in an applet, but that seems like a step backwards and I assume I'll lose preloader options. I could also just do a web start/jnlp launch, but I'd like for it to be able to be part of the webpage. What is the best course here? Go with straight JavaFX and wait for future updates?

Comment: *"I like what I see so far (mp3 support!)"*  Java Sound could support MP3 decoding by adding the [mp3plugin.jar](http://pscode.org/lib/mp3plugin.jar) of the JMF to the run-time class-path of the app.  The JMF has been around since about ..2002.

Comment: @AndrewThompson while this is true, it will be nice to have this without any additional dependencies. Also, the last stable release of JMF (not necessarily other extensions of it) was in 2003.

Comment: JMF seems more 'internal' to me than JavaFX, and the JMF decoding of MP3 was pretty stable back in 2003.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Not knocking JMF - I've used it before and like it. I'm just trying to get my feet wet with JavaFX both because it's new to me and it comes standard with JRE/JDK 1.7.0_04

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is still  something you're on, but as you commented just two days ago, maybe these hints are still useful for you.

Have you ever discovered the JNLP thing of JavaFX? Using Java WebStart gives you the ability to get your Applet / Application 'out of the browser', said in simple words. 
JavaFX provides this ability, it's a gift for you, you don't need to do anything special / no additional dependencies.

As you know, documentation about FX can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/).

Especially if you want to try JNLP, maybe you want to have a look at the [deployment choices](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) you have now.

Depending on the IDE you're using for development, you don't need to do anything special (and the links look more complicated than this all is).

I have the following setup and it works just like a charme:

- Kubuntu 12.04
- JDK 7u6 (including FX 2.2)
- Eclipse EE 4.2 Juno (The EE Version is important)
- Eclipse e(fx)clipse Plugin (available via the Eclipse market place)

Depending on if you plan to share your applicaton, maybe this is useful for you, too:
See a list for the supported platforms [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html) for FX Version 2.2

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've been reading about the different deployment options, still on the fence as to which one I'll choose. The webstart is cool, but (as far as I know), it won't allow you to embed in the actual webpage. I've been working on other stuff the past few days, but now I'm back to it and I'll try a few more different things. I may end up using a JApplet filled with JavaFX goodies as opposed to extending the javafx application.

Comment: After more reading, it seems like embedding JavaFX in a swing applet would be more trouble than it's worth. A few hoops to jump through with threads and such, plus I think I'd lose the ability to create my own preloader. I'm leaning towards just going pure JavaFX embedded and assume either I will figure out how to make it pop out if the functionality is there, or it will be added in the future. 

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm

Comment: Still I don't know why you need Swing :) I would recommend using JavaFX only, and if you are really stuck with some components, you can always go back and include Swing in FX. I'd just switch the dependencies. Use FX where possible, and include Swing, instead of using Swing and trying to include FX. (Or I simply missunderstood your last comment) :)